# Querying using array

Tags: php, mysql

There is nothing wrong with my code, but I just cant help but wonder, should I wrap the $key with mysql_real_escape_string? This is just part of my Database function which is mainly used to pull data out of the database with table name and $where as arguments to the function. $where is to be an associative array with keys being column name, and values being the data.

This is what processes the $where array. Before this I have $sql = 'select * from ' . $table;

```
if(!empty($where)){
        $where_count = count($where);

        $sql .= ' WHERE ';

        foreach($where as $key => $value){

            $split_key = explode(' ', $key);

            if(count($split_key) > 1){
                $sql .= $key[0] . ' ' . $key[1] . ' "' . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '" ';
            } else {
                $sql .= $key . ' = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '" ';
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter **ANY INPUT** from the user that is going to be placed in your query. No doubt!
So if the keys are supplied by the user, YES and if they are generated in a safe manner, NO.

Take a look at [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) to understand why filtering must be done.

Comment: Thank you. The Keys are being generated by me, so I suppose i dont need to.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is being asked here, but I can see one error:

```
$sql .= $key[0] . ' ' . $key[1] . ' "' . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '" ';
```

should be

```
$sql .= $split_key[0] . ' ' . $split_key[1] . ' "' . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '" ';
```

Comment: Thanks :) I totally didnt see that.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to quote field names, use backticks.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html

> The following statement creates a table named a`b that contains a
>   column named c"d:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `a``b` (`c"d` INT);
> ```

Comment: Dont understand how this has to do with my question, but thanks anyways dude or dudette.